# Pass Variables to Included PHP file inside a Joomla Article

Tags: php, variables, joomla, include

I'm new to Joomla, but not a new programmer.  I've written several applications in PHP that I want to include inside Joomla articles.  Simple enough:

```
<?php include 'file.php'; ?>
```

The issue is that inside the PHP files I have a bunch of code gathering and creating variables that I need to `POST` and retrieve.  I can get those `POST` variables inside the Article, but I can't pass them back to the included PHP file.

I've even coded the included PHP files to access the Joomla framework hoping to retrieve Joomla user id for example.  This won't run inside the Article either and returns empty.  However, if I run the PHP file on its own outside of the Article, I can access all `POST` data (obviously) and also the Joomla JFactory data.  So it runs fine, until it's placed as an included file inside an Article.

The only way I've been able to pass something to the included PHP file is using `$_GET` url variables like this:

```
<?php include 'file.php?data=something'; ?>
```

However, this simply isn't practical as I have too many variables to pass like this.  Normally, included PHP files run as part of the parent script and have access to all variables.  How can I accomplish this in Joomla??

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, In what file are you doing this include? Normally all available variables will be available in the included file, it will be just like an extension of the code right there where you include it. If you are doing this inside a class, you need to use $this-> ... to get the class variables.

Comment: I'm including PHP files in several Joomla articles.  That's exactly my point, normally all variables should be available to the included script and they don't appear.  POST and SESSION vars return empty for example.

Comment: Makes sense: If you are including php directly into articles, then I'm not sure how it's handled, but I guess it's eval'ed in some way. You should use another approach.

Comment: You could try Jobin's module approach below, or some other way. I'll sketch my usual approach, but it really depends what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to include php into articles. Try instead one of these approaches:

1. Load your code in the index.php - file in your template: /templates/yourtemplate/index.php. This file is called every time your page is called.
2. Make a template override of the component where you want you external php file to be loaded. If this is in an article, you copy /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php (and possibly also other files there) to /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/article. Then add your include-statement here. ([info](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)) This file will be loaded each time you view a single article, but you can have further logic to only run it if (whatever)...
3. Use Jobin Jose's approach if you want to load you php-file inside content in an article. ([info](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F))
4. Some other approach writing a [plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)
5. ...or a [component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component)

I would say probably the easiest method is 2. (or 1.), but it all depends what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments here and above.  I'll investigate these options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You have to create a simple module for your requirement, means what you are trying to achieve with included php file.

then place that module within the article with `{loadposition module_position}`
then you will get all the POST variables to that article and also suppose user_id and all other joomla Factory can be accessed bcoz its a Joomla module.

for a quick tutorial about module creation can be found [here](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial).

hope it make sense.

Comment: I'll look into this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using an Extension called Sourcerer
https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

Variables can be passed without issue now.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score -1):

Why do not you try to create a new Joomla component and do whatever you want it it?

I am absolutely beginner in php/mysql but managed to do it with my page, following this instructions:
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-component/helloworld

When you create this component, whatever you write in its "default.php" file, is actually a blank HTML/PHP page, with your joomla design and some other Joomla-features.

Sorry for the amateur answer and terminology :)

Comment: Actually no. A component's **default.php** is used for the view markup. Any PHP used to process data should be in the controller/model

Comment: Sorry, which is the "Controller/model" ?

Is it view.html.php?

However default.php also worked :)

Comment: An example would be `ROOT/components/com_content/models`. Yes, the *default.php* can be used but it's very bad practice to do this and results in there being no need for a component. You may as well use a single PHP file if this is the route you wish to take

Comment: My hope is to avoid rewriting all of the code I'm wanting to include which I imagine I'd have to do in order to create a component.